# installing netbeans-8.0.1-javaee-linux.sh on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: netbeans

I have downloaded netbeans-8.0.1-javaee-linux.sh.

I have run sudo chmod +x to make it executable
But how do I install it?

It I try double-clicking it wants to open with gedit
If I "Open With" --> Ubuntu Software Centre, it says The file “/home/mike/Downloads/netbeans-8.0.1-javaee-linux.sh” could not be opened.

How do I install it? Thanks.

Comment: java version "1.7.0_65"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea 2.5.2) (7u65-2.5.2-3~14.04)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.65-b04, mixed mode)

Answer (score 3):

Open a terminal (use `Ctrl+Alt+T`), change to the directory containing the downloaded shell script, and run as super user:

```
$ sudo ./netbeans-8.0.1-javaee-linux.sh
```

You'll be prompted for your password and the NetBeans install wizard will start.

Answer (score 1):

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> on your keyboard to open the terminal. When it opens, run the command below to make the installer executable.

`chmod +x netbeans-8.0.1-javaee-linux.sh.`

Run as super user:

Start the installer:

`./netbeans-8.0.1-javaee-linux.sh`